# How to replace values less than 10 in several columns with "<10"?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset of over 10,000 and I was wondering how to suppress the file by replacing values that are less than 10 with <10?

I tried using the IF function: 
=IF(G4:I22726<10, "<10")

but it gave me an error.

The range G4:I22726 are the columns of the the table that contains numbers.

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: What was the error? Where are you putting your formula?

Comment: I highlighted the range G4:I22726 and then I put the formula in the first cell of the range (G4) since it automatically gets inputted in the cell I select first to highlight. The error is a Circular Reference Warning.

Comment: Right - you need to put the formula somewhere else. See my answer (method 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in one of two ways.

1) create a new range with a formula that computes the value you want; then copy the range, do a "paste-special-values" on top of the old data, and finally delete your temporary range; or
2) Use a small VBA macro:

```
Sub lessThan()
On Error Resume Next
For Each c in Range("G4:I22726").Cells
  if c.Value < 10 Then c.Text = "<10"
Next
End Sub
```

Run this macro just once and you're done.

The reason your original attempt generated an error is that your formula was referencing itself - that is what Excel calls a circular reference. A formula cannot depend on its own result, as it might never finish calculating (although in this case it would).

**UPDATE**
Showing how using a formula would work:

[image]

The formula shown in the formula bar was entered in cell `C1`, then dragged to `D1`. Finally I double-clicked the little box in the bottom right hand corner which automatically copied the formula all the way down to the bottom of the list (in this case, row 5; in your case it would copy down 22k rows).

Then you copy the selected range, and paste-special-values it on top of cell A1 (it will overwrite everything else). After that, delete columns C and D.

Comment: I was just wondering, what do you do to avoid referencing itself?

Comment: When you type a formula, Excel shows the range you refer to (in color). If your formula is in the colored section, you are referencing yourself. In your case, if you just consider columns G and I "out of bounds" you can put something in J (or K, etc) and you're good to go. By the way - do you understand how to use a macro? Do I need to expand the answer a bit?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't know how to use a macro since it is not needed at the moment. Can you please explain what your first way means? What do you mean by "copy the range" and "paste-special-values"? Do you mean something like =IF(J4:L22726<10, "<10")?

Comment: Literally - from the Edit menu, select "Paste Special..." - in the dialog that pops up, select "Values". This replaces formulas with the computed values (and prevents circular references...)

Comment: As for the macro - if you type Alt-F11 you will find yourself in the VBA editor. Click "Insert-New Module", paste the above code, put your mouse cursor on the "Sub" line and hit the "Run" button.

Comment: Oh I see. I have two questions though. Since my dataset is over 20000, is there another way than dragging to the end of the range? Also, how can I leave the cell blank instead of inserting a zero if it was originally blank? Sorry for asking so many questions!

Comment: As long as your range has values in every row, the "double click" trick I described will work without you needing to drag all the way down; but the macro is much more suitable for this. If you want an empty cell to remain empty you can use a formula (like) `=IF(A1="", "", IF(A1<10,"<10",A1))` - or in the macro, add similar logic.

Answer (score 5):

Without altering the actual cell contents, the appearance of "<10" can be achieved for values under 10 with custom formatting, such as:

```
[<10]"<10";General
```

Comment: That is a _really_ nice trick! Seriously - I learn something new/interesting most days - but this is an outlier of "wow" proportions.

Answer (score 3):

Enter the following formula in J4:

```
=IF(G4<10,"<10",G4)
```

Copy this to the range J4:L22726 so that it mirrors the entire range you are referencing. This will create another range of cells with the result you are looking for.

Comment: How come I put the formula in J4, but not in the original data? It works, but then I don't understand the logistics behind it. How does excel know the range ends at I22726?

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at another file. The function does not seem to work. There were no changes made..